# Is is possible a integer reset to zero due to Java / Android GC?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I've read a [blog post](http://fred-zone.blogspot.com/2011/11/android.html) (sorry it's written in Chinese) which the author says:

> This is a web-related app, we declare some private variable, when user
>   have done some operations, these variable will be set to some value for later use.
>
> Normally the app is running well, but when we open some website with
>   heavy JavaScript, our application starts to behave incorrectly and
>   unexpected (without any Activity switching), we can not find why.
>
> Finally, we found that this is caused by a integer variable has been
>   set to zero. But we are very certain that our code won't reset it to
>   zero, so there is only one possible conclusion: "In order to satisfy
>   the resource required by WebView, Garbage Collector has collected our
>   variable". So at last we set declare this variable as a static variable to avoid this problem.

To be frank, this "GC set a int to zero" argument is total contrary to my Java knowledge.

Because as far as I know:

1. The collection unit of Java GC is object, and primitive type int is not object in Java.
2. The life time of a instance variable is same to the life time of the owner object, and the memory use by that instance variable is freed when that object has being collected by GC.
3. Even that variable is a Integer object instead of primitive int thus could be collected, as long as there is a reachable reference to it, it won't be collected.
4. Even we use WeakReference to store the Integer reference to make that Integer object collectible, after the Integer object has been collected, we could not access to that already freed object's memory in anyway.

But I'm also worried about if there are something I didn't considered.

So I'm very interested in the following question:

1. I there any possible situation a int or Integer object could be reset to zero due to Garbage Collection?
2. Is it possible GC only freed partial memory space (like only one instance variable) an object takes, instead of full object?
3. Is it possible to have a reference to a already garbage collected object, and what will happen if we dereference it?
4. What is the most possible scenario to this case assuming that variable are reset to zero randomly, and its not cause by their code. VM bugs? GC bugs? JIT bugs or anything else?

Comment: reason is (probably) that their Activity in background get's destroyed and recreated. Private variables will be what they are initially.

Comment: @zapl: No, they said there is no Activity switching when this phenomenon happened.

Comment: Then it's something else like using the wrong instance of an Object or actually setting the variable to 0 in a hidden place. Rename variable, add a getter / setter that prints access and check what changes it. Chances that this is an external bug (memory corruption, native code writing into wrong place, ..) are very small

Answer (score 7):

> I there any possible situation a int or Integer object could be reset to zero due to Garbage Collection?

If the object holding the `int` or `Integer` itself was garabage-collected and later re-created by application code, it would appear to the outside that the `int` or `Integer` was reset.

Otherwise, no.

> Is it possible GC only freed partial space that an object takes, instead of full objects?

Only if you are using stuff like `WeakReference` as your connection to the "partial space".

> Is it possible to have a reference to a already garbage collected object

No. If you can reach it, it cannot be garbage-collected.

> what will happen if we dereference it?

There will be a rupture in the space-time continuum, ending reality as we know it.

Comment: So please, don't dereference references that you can not have! That's serious business!